# Executing Create Function on Aurora Serverless instance of Postgres fails

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to enable PostGIS extensions on an Aurora Serverless Postgres 10.7 instance using the instructions provided by AWS ([found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS)) and executing the steps via the Query Editor in the RDS console. Using these same instructions I was able to successfully execute all the commands on a separate, regular Aurora RDS Postgres instance.

In "Step 4: Transfer Ownership of the Objects to the rds_superuser Role" I'm getting this error:

[image]

This also fails if you try and execute the command from the AWS cli using:

```
aws rds-data execute-statement --resource-arn "<<RESOURCE_ARN>>" \
--database "postgres" --secret-arn "<<SECRET_ARN>>" \
--sql "CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN $1; END; $f$;"
```

How do I execute these functions via either the RDS Query Editor or the AWS cli?

Answer (score 1):

The RDS Query Editor and the AWS cli both require '$' characters to be escaped. Simply escaping all the instances of the '$' with '\$' does the trick.

```
aws rds-data execute-statement --resource-arn "<<RESOURCE_ARN>>" \
--database "postgres" --secret-arn "<<SECRET_ARN>>" \
--sql "CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS \$f\$ BEGIN EXECUTE \$1; RETURN \$1; END; \$f\$;"
```

Comment: For someone who is trying to make it work through AWS Query Editor or Windows (10) PowerShell or CMD, this solution will not work. I even tried to reproduce the same function as OP but it failed. I tried different solutions to escape $ but it didn't work. Finally, I was able to do it via Ubuntu using solution posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994804/how-do-i-create-user-defined-function-in-aws-aurora-rds-postgres

P.S. Not sure if this is the best solution but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: great comment - I was not aware of the fact that you need to escape the '$' character. I was already going crazy of RDS editor not taking my statement. Thank you!